# c# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have an output like -

```
Col.A              Col.B  Col.C  Col.D
--------------------------------------------------------------
* 1  S60-01-GE-44T-AC   SGFM115001195  7520051202   A
  1  S60-PWR-AC         APFM115101302  7520047802   A
  1  S60-PWR-AC         APFM115101245  7520047802   A
```

or

```
 Col.A               Col.B  Col.C  Col.D
--------------------------------------------------------------
* 0  S50-01-GE-48T-AC   DL252040175    7590005605   B
  0  S50-PWR-AC         N/A            N/A          N/A
  0  S50-FAN            N/A            N/A          N/A
```

For these outputs the regular expression -

```
(?:\*)?\s+(?<unitno>\d+)\s+\S+-\d+-(?:GE|TE)?-?(?:\d+(?:F|T))-?(?:(?:AC)|V)?\s+(?<serial>\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\n
```

works fine to capture Column A and Column B. But recently I got a new kind of output -

```
 Col.A               Col.B  Col.C  Col.D  
---------------------------------------------------------
* 0  S4810-01-64F       HADL120620060  7590009602   A        
  0  S4810-PWR-AC       H6DL120620060  7590008502   A          
  0  S4810-FAN          N/A            N/A          N/A         
  0  S4810-FAN          N/A            N/A          N/A
```

As you can see the patterns **"GE|TE"** and the **"AC|V"** are missing from these outputs. How do I change my regular expression accordingly maintaining backward compatibility.

EDIT:

The output that you see comes in a complete string and due to some operational limits I cannot use any other concept other than regex here to get my desired values. I know using split would be ideal here but I cannot.

Comment: Can you not just parse the columns based on whitespace? It seems fine with the examples you have given, saves messing around with regex

Comment: Can you please provide some samples of what the `INPUT` looks like?

Comment: want I am interested in knowing here is that how do u solve this problem by adding on to the present regex...because I feel the current regex should work for the new output also but it isn't. I doubt it is because some patterns missing..

Comment: Have you tried using the regex toolkit in Monodevelop? It's great for feeding it input and testing your regex against it to ensure that it only validates the data you want. I keep Monodevelop installed along side VS just for this tool.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression seems not to be the right approach here. Use a positional approach

```
string s = "* 0  S4810-01-64F       HADL120620060  7590009602   A";

bool withStar = s[0] == '*';
string nr = s.Substring(2, 2).Trim();
string colA = s.Substring(5, 18).TrimEnd();
string colB = s.Substring(24, 14).TrimEnd();
...
```

---

**UPDATE**

I you want (or must) stick to Regex, test for the spaces instead of the values. Of cause this works only if the values never include spaces.

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(s, "\s+");
```

---

Of cause you can also search for non-spaces `\S` instead of `\s`.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, "\S+");
```

or excluding the star

```
(?:\*)?[^*\s]+
```

Comment: thanks for the other approach Olivier but won't help much. I HAVE TO use regex..there is some concept of DTO'S etc.. Can't escape regex here..

Answer (score 2):

You are probably better off using String.Split() to break the column values out into sperate strings and then processing them, rather that using a huge un-readable regular expression.

```
foreach (string line in lines) {
    string[] colunnValues = line.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ...
}
```

Comment: You should use `line.Split((char[])null, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` instead. This accounts for all whitespace, not just tabs.

Answer (score 1):

your regular expression doesn't even need `GE` or `TE`.  See that `?` after `(?:GE|TE)`?

that means that the previous group or symbol is optional.

the same is true with the `AC` and `V` section

Answer (score 1):

I would not use regular expressions to parse these reports.

Instead, treat them as fixed column width reports after the headers are stripped off.

I would do something like (this is typed cold as an example, not tested even for syntax):

```
   // Leaving off all public/private/error detection stuff
   class ColumnDef  
   {
        string Name { set; get; } 
        int FirstCol { set; get; }
        int LastCol { set; get; }
   }

   ColumnDef[] report = new ColumnDef[] 
   {
         { Name = "ColA",
           FirstCol = 0,
           LastCol = 2
         },
         /// ... and so on for each column
   }

   IDictionary<string, string> ParseDataLine(string line) 
   {
       var dummy = new Dictionary<string, string>();
       foreach (var c in report) 
       {
          dummy[c.Name] = line.Substring(c.FirstCol, c.LastCol).Trim();
       }
   }
```

This is an example of a generic ETL (Extract, Transform, and Load) problem--specifically the Extract stage.

You will have to strip out header and footer lines before using `ParseDataLine`, and I am not sure there is enough information shown to do that.  Based on what your post says, any line that is blank, or doesn't start with a space or a `*` is a header/footer line to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try something like this `(?:\*)?\s+(?<unitno>\d+)\s+\S+\s+(?<serial>\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+(?:\s+)?\n`

This is built off your provided regular expression and due to the trailing `\n` the provided input will need to end with a carriage return.